# Replace a word (or many words) with spaces of same length?

Tags: vim

In a general sense, my question is how do I do something like "dw" or "dd", but instead of deleting characters, I want to over-write with spaces?

E.g. lets say I have text:

```
first second third
```

if the cursor is on the "s" in second, I can hit "dw" to get:

```
first third
```

but what if I want:

```
first        third
```

Is there a simple way to do that? An ideal solution would be to use the "d" style syntax (e.g. dw, daw, d$, etc.) but with whitespace replacement instead of deletion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of their very nature (the next character must be consumed), `r` and `R` can't work like operators. If you want to replace a motion, visually select it first, and then do `r<Space>` or `r_` or whatever.

In this very specific case:

```
ver<Space>
```

or:

```
viwr<Space>
```

NOTE: I used `ve` and `viw` because the semantics of `w` are inconsistent so I prefer to avoid it when possible.

Comment: Both these answers are great (and similar), I'll go with this one due to avoiding the control key

Answer (score 3):

From the start of the word,

- Ctrl-v to enter visual block mode,
- e to move to the end of the word (highlighting the word in the process),
- r[SPACE] to replace the highlighted characters with spaces.

Comment: Alternative way to select a word: `viw`

Comment: In combination with, say, "j" or "k" this is a great way to get a vertical section of whitespace.  Not what I was asking, but something I also like to do sometimes!